# Matching columns in R and adding frequencies against them

Tags: r

I need to match my values in col1 with col 2 and col3 and if they match i need to add their frequencies.It should display the count from freq1 freq2 and freq3 of the unique values.

```
    col1    freq1   col2    freq2   col3    freq3
    apple   3   grapes  4   apple   1
    grapes  5   apple   2   orange  2
    orange  4   banana  5   grapes  2
    guava   3   orange  6   banana  7

I need my output like this
apple   6
grapes  11
orange  12
guava   3
banana  12
```

I m a beginner.How do I code this in R.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` with `patterns` specified in the `measure` argument to convert the 'wide' format to 'long' format, then grouped by 'col', we get the `sum` of 'freq' column

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^col", "^freq"),
         value.name = c("col", "freq"))[,.(freq = sum(freq)) , by =  col]
#      col freq
#1:  apple    6
#2: grapes   11
#3: orange   12
#4:  guava    3
#5: banana   12
```

---

If it is alternating 'col', 'freq', columns, we can just `unlist` the subset of 'col' columns and 'freq' columns separately to create a data.frame (using `c(TRUE, FALSE)` to recycle for subsetting columns), and then use `aggregate` from `base R` to get the `sum` grouped by 'col'.

```
 aggregate(freq~col, data.frame(col = unlist(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
           freq = unlist(df1[c(FALSE, TRUE)])), sum)
#    col freq
#1  apple    6
#2 banana   12
#3 grapes   11
#4  guava    3
#5 orange   12
```

Comment: Thanks I got to leran a new thing using this aggregate function alongwith my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest to understand for newbie would be creating 3 separate dataframes (I assumed here that your dataframe name is df):

```
df1 <- data.frame(df$col1, df$freq1)
colnames(df1) <- c("fruit", "freq")
df2 <- data.frame(df$col2, df$freq2)
colnames(df2) <- c("fruit", "freq")
df3 <- data.frame(df$col3, df$freq3)
colnames(df3) <- c("fruit", "freq")
```

Then bind all dataframes by rows:

```
df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

And at the end group by fruit and sum frequencies using dplyr library.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
       group_by(fruit)%>%
       summarise(sum(freq))
```

Comment: Thanks..I understood.I am now getting the desired output.